# Why is time converted to index in pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, indexing

When working with pandas dataframes where one of the columns is time, why do we generally convert the time column to the index? What is the advantage?

I can implement the indexing but not sure what the gains are

Comment: Generally? What do you mean? If you're dealing with [time-series data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), then yeah of course the time should be the index (like say, readings from a sensor or group of sensors), but not if you're dealing with other data, like say, time of death in medical records. Check out the user guide: [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html). (All that said, I have very little data science experience myself, so grain of salt.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dti = pd.date_range('2024-1-27', periods=24, freq='H')
temp = np.random.randint(10, 25, len(dti))
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': dti, 'Temperature': temp})
print(df)

              DateTime  Temperature
0  2024-01-27 00:00:00           10
1  2024-01-27 01:00:00           21
2  2024-01-27 02:00:00           24
3  2024-01-27 03:00:00           18
4  2024-01-27 04:00:00           12
5  2024-01-27 05:00:00           16
6  2024-01-27 06:00:00           16
7  2024-01-27 07:00:00           15
8  2024-01-27 08:00:00           10
9  2024-01-27 09:00:00           20
10 2024-01-27 10:00:00           12
11 2024-01-27 11:00:00           18
12 2024-01-27 12:00:00           24
13 2024-01-27 13:00:00           17
14 2024-01-27 14:00:00           21
15 2024-01-27 15:00:00           15
16 2024-01-27 16:00:00           20
17 2024-01-27 17:00:00           16
18 2024-01-27 18:00:00           14
19 2024-01-27 19:00:00           12
20 2024-01-27 20:00:00           24
21 2024-01-27 21:00:00           24
22 2024-01-27 22:00:00           16
23 2024-01-27 23:00:00           16
```

If you want to select rows between 13:00 and 17:00, you should do:

```
>>> df[df['DateTime'].between('2024-01-27 13:00:00', '2024-01-27 17:00:00')]
              DateTime  Temperature
13 2024-01-27 13:00:00           17
14 2024-01-27 14:00:00           21
15 2024-01-27 15:00:00           15
16 2024-01-27 16:00:00           20
17 2024-01-27 17:00:00           16
```

And suppose you want to resample your values (3H average):

```
>>> df.resample('3H', on='DateTime').mean().reset_index()
             DateTime  Temperature
0 2024-01-27 00:00:00    18.333333
1 2024-01-27 03:00:00    15.333333
2 2024-01-27 06:00:00    13.666667
3 2024-01-27 09:00:00    16.666667
4 2024-01-27 12:00:00    20.666667
5 2024-01-27 15:00:00    17.000000
6 2024-01-27 18:00:00    16.666667
7 2024-01-27 21:00:00    18.666667
```

Now we define `DateTime` column as index:

```
>>> df = df.set_index('DateTime')
                     Temperature
DateTime                        
2024-01-27 00:00:00           10
2024-01-27 01:00:00           21
2024-01-27 02:00:00           24
2024-01-27 03:00:00           18
2024-01-27 04:00:00           12
2024-01-27 05:00:00           16
2024-01-27 06:00:00           16
2024-01-27 07:00:00           15
2024-01-27 08:00:00           10
2024-01-27 09:00:00           20
2024-01-27 10:00:00           12
2024-01-27 11:00:00           18
2024-01-27 12:00:00           24
2024-01-27 13:00:00           17
2024-01-27 14:00:00           21
2024-01-27 15:00:00           15
2024-01-27 16:00:00           20
2024-01-27 17:00:00           16
2024-01-27 18:00:00           14
2024-01-27 19:00:00           12
2024-01-27 20:00:00           24
2024-01-27 21:00:00           24
2024-01-27 22:00:00           16
2024-01-27 23:00:00           16
```

And do same operations:

```
>>> df['2024-01-27 13:00:00':'2024-01-27 17:00:00']
                     Temperature
DateTime                        
2024-01-27 13:00:00           17
2024-01-27 14:00:00           21
2024-01-27 15:00:00           15
2024-01-27 16:00:00           20
2024-01-27 17:00:00           16

>>> df.resample('3H').mean()
                     Temperature
DateTime                        
2024-01-27 00:00:00    18.333333
2024-01-27 03:00:00    15.333333
2024-01-27 06:00:00    13.666667
2024-01-27 09:00:00    16.666667
2024-01-27 12:00:00    20.666667
2024-01-27 15:00:00    17.000000
2024-01-27 18:00:00    16.666667
2024-01-27 21:00:00    18.666667
```

This is obviously more concise writing. There is logic to set `DateTime` as index when you process TimeSeries: data is a function of time!

Suggested by @wjandrea: [Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html)

Comment: it is more concise and better. Take the time column and converting it into the index is an efficient move. In general, I assume the same reasoning applies to other cases, not involving time, where we take a column in the dataframe and make it the index instead of keeping the default 1,2,3,4...Thank you